# Convert canvas to OpenGl

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-canvas

Can you show me how to implement this canvas function using opneGL es1:

```
public void drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top, Paint paint)
```

I need full example with activity and a view.

@broschb
I simply want to set up the screen size and draw a 2d image within a given (x,y) coordination according to my set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a GLSurfaceView to draw on.  You will then need to convert your bitmap to a texture and then you can draw the texture, or texture a quad.  Look at the tutorial, it's a simple start.

Also, if you give more details on what you are trying to achieve, you will probably receive more specific answers to help.

http://www.anddev.org/android-2d-3d-graphics-opengl-problems-f55/draw-a-bitmap-using-opengl-t14920.html

Comment: I think that tutorial will give you all the building blocks you need to get started. Basically you just need to create a quad(in android you will need to use vertices), and then just convert your bitmap to a texture and apply it to the quad.  you can then apply transforms to your current view matrix in opengl.  I would also checkout some opengl tutorials, there are some great ones of the nehe tutorials ported to android here.http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/